# In Ruby How to sort an array of numbers in descending order

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

In Ruby How to sort an array of numbers in descending order

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

the out put to be `[4,3,2,1]`

I have looked for ways to do it but they are all either 10 years old or 8 years old nothing at least with the past 3 years.

Comment: "they are all either 10 years old or 8 years old" - but do they work?

Comment: Chances are, sorting wasn’t that different in 2012 ;-)

Comment: the goal of the question was to bring about more morden methods or build in functions. Nothing against the older ways  it was meant only to bring a more variety

Answer (score 6):

Input

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

One way

```
p a.sort { |a, b| b <=> a }
```

another way

```
p a.sort_by { _1 }.reverse
```

another way

```
p a.sort_by { |x| -x }
```

Output

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Raj, you forgot `a.max(a.size)`. :-)

Comment: `p a.sort_by { -_1 }`